# Python, Lists error: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, loops, python-3.6, bubble-sort

I have been working on a program that takes a string and sorts it into alphabetical order (Bubble sort). I made a simple piece of code to start me off but i came across a problem shortly after running it in shell.
My code:

```
aList = ["b", "a", "d", "c"]
compOne = 0
compTwo = 1
sorting = True
while sorting == True:
    print (aList)
    sortingList = []
    sortingList.insert(compOne, aList[compOne])
    sortingList.insert(compTwo, aList[compTwo])
    aList[compOne] = sorted(sortingList)[compOne]
    aList[compTwo] = sorted(sortingList)[compTwo]
    print (aList)
    print("__________________________")
    compOne = compOne + 1
    compTwo = compTwo + 1
```

The idea i had is it will keep going through the list swapping items until it is in alphabetical order (I have not closed the while loop yet, i will proceed to do this when i have got pass this problem) 
The output i want:

```
['a', 'b', 'd', 'c']
__________________________
['a', 'b', 'd', 'c']
__________________________
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
__________________________
ETC(Will repeat because i haven't closed the while loop)
```

The output i get along with the error:

```
['a', 'b', 'd', 'c']
__________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/Python Programs/Projects/Bubble Sort/Test File 4.py", line 10, in <module>
    aList[compTwo] = sorted(sortingList)[compTwo]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

As you can tell it came to the second set of items to be compared and came across this error. For some reason 
`aList[compOne] = sorted(sortingList)[compOne]` was fine but `aList[compTwo] = sorted(sortingList)[compTwo]` wasn't (Suggesting they are similiar code)

I have been investigating this problem for an 1 hour and half and i have not found a solution, if you can tell me the problem and explain in depth why this happened i would greatly appreciate it.(I don't just want the answer but i want an explanation with what i did wrong) Meanwhile i am waiting for a answer and explanation i will look into the problem myself. Thanks. (Written in python 3.6.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CompOne` starts at `0`

`CompTwo` starts at `1`

You `add 1` to both all the time - until `CompOne` adresses the last character of the string (which is fine) and `CompTwo` tries to access the character *after* the last character of the string  -> `Indexerror`.

I am unsure if I grasp correctly what you try to do, what boggles me most:

- you reinstantiate your `sortingList` on every while-loop-round to an empty list?
- on each while loop you put char `n` and 'n+1' into your array at some indexes
- your sortingList is sorted twice (sorted(.....)) which creates new list twice which is quite unnessecary - you could simply sort it once and store that in a temp var that you acess. Why do you use `.insert` with an index here, the list is empty beside the two chars you put into it due to the `sortedList=[]` couple lines before

You need to heed the length of your input array, `CompTwo` can not exceed that.

Comment: Thanks, you answered the problem i was having. I would like to know what you meant by i sorted the variable twice, i had a good look at the code and could not see anything that sorted it twice. The only time it is sorted is in:
    `aList[compOne] = sorted(sortingList)[compOne]
    aList[compTwo] = sorted(sortingList)[compTwo]` which are sorted as separate.

Comment: No - `sorted(sortingList)` will sort the whole list and create a new copied over new one (it does not sort in-place) and the added `[compOne]` uses the n-th element of this list - then you do the same again and access the n+1th  element yet another  copied&sorted list. See https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sorted   :o)